# Why should separate accounts be used for SharePoint admin roles?

Tags: security, sharepoint-2013

Every guide, blog and the health analyser keeps saying that you need to set up different accounts for different services, farm account and application pool accounts.

But no-one want to explain me why! I have tried to search for an answer, and while I am pretty sure it has a good reason I just cannot seem to find one. I really would like to know why. I want to learn! Try to be concrete!

To narrow down the question a bit. What are the reason for these two security issues reported by the health analyser:

- The server farm account should not be used for other services.
- Accounts used by application pools or service identities are in the local machine Administrators group.

Comment: Because you don't want just anyone to be able to go in and modify critical services or allow access to your server. It's called common sense - you don't put a lock on your front door and then leave the key in it so just anyone can go inside, do you? When you create a PIN for your bank account, you and your spouse are the only ones that get it, so that your children and relatives don't have free access to your account. If they need access to some of the money, you set up a separate account and give them access to that account, and then you can put in the amount you want to share with them.

Comment: How exactly am i allowing "just anyone" to access my server? Thats what I would like to know.

Comment: The key to any kind of security is restricting access. If you use the same account for multiple services, you're allowing anyone who gains access to one server to have access to all the others as well. How much more concrete can it be? If you have 10 buildings, and make a master key that will open the doors on all buildings, then someone who steals your key to building 1 can also open the doors on buildings 2-10 with the same key. If you have a different key for each of the 10 buildings, the person stealing the key to building 1 can only access building 1 with that key.